# Not able to start all nodes

Tags: corda

Just now i converted the version from 1.0 to 3.1 by doing some changes in build.gradle file. I have 8 nodes include notary and built successfully. Moment i give runnodes.bat, all gets started to execute. But at the end, only fours nodes got started completed others throwing error like below

```
[INFO ] 2018-06-05T11:18:13,500Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - 
Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : localhost:10013 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-05T11:18:13,509Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - RPC 
connection address                  : 0.0.0.0:10014 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-05T11:18:13,510Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - RPC 
admin connection address            : 0.0.0.0:10054 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-05T11:18:25,142Z [main] 
messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.configureAndStartServer - P2P messaging 
server listening on port 10013 {}
[ERROR] 2018-06-05T11:18:35,955Z [main] core.server.run - AMQ224000: Failure 
in initialisation {}
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
atio.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.
doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.
bind(AbstractChannel.java:554)
~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.
bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.
invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.
bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.
bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250) ~[netty-
all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365) ~
[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.
safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.
runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.
run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
[WARN ] 2018-06-05T11:18:38,237Z [main] 
utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.set - Double insert in 
net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMap for entity class class 
net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$Persistent
Identity key 
244940BA312445680AE417765E703E2E4F551242FFE5F53256DFA58CCFE2EAA9, not 
inserting the second time {}
[ERROR] 2018-06-05T11:18:38,244Z [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during 
node startup {}
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel. 
doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.
bind(AbstractChannel.java:554) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.
bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.
invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501) ~[netty-all-
4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
```

I have updated the error. Please do check

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to the node's RPC settings.

Try changing the `address` and `adminAddress` of your node's RPC settings to `0.0.0.0`, leaving the port untouched. For example:

```
rpcSettings {
    address="0.0.0.0:10010"
    adminAddress="0.0.0.0:10011"
}
```

These addresses do not need to be accessible from other nodes, as they are solely used by the node itself during start-up.

Comment: still same issue @Joel

Comment: i have updated above answer. Still am facing same issue @Joel

Comment: corda webserver started correctly. but corda jar are not able to get start

Comment: Can you check the nodes' logs please, and update your question with any relevant error messages?